# Align navbar-brand with page

Tags: html, css

I have this page here [demoPage](https://ibb.co/jTKWDz) I am trying to make my navbar brand reponsive with the page. For now i have added custom padding with navbar-brand but i want it to be responsive with the page if i change the size of my browser. Also i want a little space between my school title and its logo. How can i do that? I have written this page in an angular component

```css
hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.alignLeft {
  float: left;
}

.indented {
  padding-left: 50pt;
  padding-right: 50pt;
}

.col-sm-9 {
  background-color: white;
}

img {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

h4,
p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: justify !important;
}

.para1 {
  text-align: center !important;
}

h4:first-child {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 20px !important;
}

h4:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left !important;
}

p:first-child {
  text-align: center !important;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: left !important;
  float: left !important;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  h4,
  p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: justify !important;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    text-align: justify !important;
  }
}

.columns1 {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.center2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 400px;
  padding-right: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding-left: 300px;
}

.jumbotron {
  align-items: center;
}

.center1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 140px;
}

.footer-copyright {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  padding-right: 70px;
}

.footer {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: none;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.footer a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 450px;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
}



.navbar .navbar-brand {
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> HTML Code

<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><i class="fa 
    fa-cubes"></i> GEP <span class="header-logo-text">Learning Management 
    System</span></a>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="center2">
        <div class="columns1 text-center">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/school.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left; border:2px solid gray; border-radius: 50%; display: inline; width:90px; height:80px; margin-top:60px; margin-left: 20px;">
          <h4 align="left" style="margin-top: 90px;">
            School Name/ Title<br><br><br>
          </h4>
          <br>
          <hr>
          <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo </p>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:200px;height:200px;">
            <p><span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br>Ut enim ad minim
              veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:200px;height:200px;">
            <p><span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br>Ut enim ad minim
              veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            </p>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:200px;height:200px;">
            <p><span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br>Ut enim ad minim
              veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            </p>
          </div>
          <br>
          <hr>
          <div>
            <h3>Address</h3>
            <i class="material-icons" style="color:red;">location_on</i><span id="txt1">Address,County,City,District</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <a href="">
        <h3>Gep Learning Management Sytem</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you have this in your html code? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: nope as i said this code is written in an angular component so this line is written only in the root html module file

Comment: You need to specify the `meta` tag above in your template first as to maintain the viewport on mobile devices. 
Besides, Bootstrap also support a responsive navbar i think you can reuse its structure with a little modification https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

Comment: in the index.html file of root module file this tag is specified there so when i am working inside any other child module that line will remain effective for every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i solved this

```css
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.alignLeft {
    float: left;
}

.indented{padding-left: 50pt; padding-right: 50pt;}

.col-sm-9 {
    background-color: white; 
}

img {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}



h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

h4, p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: justify !important;
}

.para1 {
    text-align: center !important;
}


h4:first-child {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px !important;
}

h4:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left !important;
}

p:first-child { 
    text-align: center !important; 
}

p:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: left !important;
    float:  left !important;
}

.center3 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 65%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.columns1 {
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/school.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
.center2{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 65%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    
}

i.material-icons {
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    font-size: 17px !important;
}

.center2 .footer {
    bottom: 0;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 300px;
 
}

.jumbotron {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


.navbar {
    align-items: center;
}

.center1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 140px;
}

.footer-copyright {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding-right: 70px;
}


.footer {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: grey; 
    bottom: 0;
    margin : auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 12;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.footer a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.container-fluid {
    background-color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) { 
    .center2 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .center3 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .img-responsive {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="center3">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> GEP
        <span class="header-logo-text">Learning Management System</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="center2">
        <div class="columns1 text-center">
 
          <div class="thumb"></div>
          <h4 align="left" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <span style="margin-left: 20px;">School Name</span>
          </h4>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <hr>
          <section>
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;">
              <p>
                <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
                <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <section>
            <div>
              <h3><u>Address</u></h3>
              <i class="material-icons" style="color:red; ">location_on</i>
              <span id="txt1" style="font-size: 15px;">Address,County,City,District</span>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
      <div>
        <a href="">
          <h3>Gep Learning Management System</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

On your `navbar-brand`, add the class of `mx-auto`

```
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><i class="fa 
fa-cubes"></i> GEP <span class="header-logo-text">Learning Management 
System</span></a>
```

Then, in your css, remove the `padding-left` that you added to `.navbar-brand`.

```
.navbar-brand {
    /*padding-left: 450px;*/
}
```

As for the space between the logo and school title, you can add a class of `mr-1`, `mr-2`, or `mr-3` (or 4, or 5) to the `img`, depending on how much space you want.

```
<img class="img-responsive mr-2" src="/assets/images/school.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left; border:2px solid gray; border-radius: 50%; display: inline; width:90px; height:80px; margin-top:60px; margin-left: 20px;">
```

`mx-auto` centers content.

`mr-1` (or 2, 3, etc.) adds margin-right (hence "m" and "r").

Check out the documentation on spacing on Bootstrap 4:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

I'm assuming you are using Bootstrap 4. :)

Comment: well you were right about the margin issue but not about the navbar issue. Because i do am using bootstrap 4 but mx-auto is not making any change in the navbar logo

Comment: Did you remove the padding? It's working for me. I'm assuming you just want the logo to always be centered, right?

Comment: i want the logo to be in alignment with the jumbotron and yes i did remove the padding

Comment: Sorry, looking at your demopage again... I think I made a mistake. On that page, your logo is on the left. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes that's what i want, i want i to stay in alignment with jumbotron 'responsively'

Comment: In that case, then yeah, now I can see why you added padding-left. 
From my point of view, it seems to be aligned with the jumbotron. I plugged your code into a file and am looking at it on a browser.
The only time it looks misaligned is when your jumbotron is really, really narrow at about less than 1235px screen width. At that point, they're still aligned, but your brand text starts to become longer than the jumbotron. You could use media queries to change the size.

Comment: And do you really need to have 400px padding to the left and right of your jumbotron all the time? It makes your jumbotron super narrow when the screen gets smaller. Like at 1200px screen width, that makes your jumbotron only 400px wide.
You could adjust that by changing the padding using media queries, then you can also adjust padding-left of your navbar-brand using media queries. Bootstrap only has 4 breakpoints, so it shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: You are absolutely right, i have decided to put the logo in the center now, so now i can breathe easily, and i was using chrome inspect tools to test the browser view on different mobile devices and the navbar was really messing up the design so now setting it into the center by throwing navbar-brand into a div has saved me from headache

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that!